# Do we need to sign our .apk file everytime we build it?

Tags: android, android-app-signing

Do we need to have the .apk signed key in order to install the app on a device and debug it if we have the source code?

I have the app code but doesn't have the key that is used to sign the certificate. Without signing from that key I can't install that app on the device. (Device has a customized Android OS which restrict installing apps which are singed by third party keys)

Comment: No. you can run code and install in device with debug mode. Sign mode only required while you want to publish application on play store.

Answer (score 3):

In order to install an apk file, it must be signed. What? Yes, even you are debugging the app, it still needs to be signed.

But, by default, when building the APK from Android studio, it will be signed with a debug key.

And you will need to sign the apk with a release key, if you want to publish the app.

You can create a release key and sign with it from android studio itself. Just go to build menu and select "Generate signed apk".

You can also run the app directly from android studio so that the app will be signed with a debug signature itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need the key store only if you need to publish an app to the play store. If you have the source code, you can just build the app and install it on your device, but first you must uninstall any previous signed versions (i.e. the ones installed from play store), in order to install the debug version, otherwise you might get incompatibility errors.

Comment: "You need the key store only if you need to publish an app to the play store. ".  This is the distinction I was looking for and seems poorly documented (on the net in general), assuming it's accurate.  Thank you.

Comment: @JulienLamarche Well technically, "You need *to create* a keystore only if you need to publish...". A keystore is still needed for APK generation, but the already present default debug keystore is used for debug builds (and can also be used for any builds from command line, iirc)